# POST form data to another form inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

So i am running a `JX Browser` which allows content to be shown in an `iframe`. When someone logs into my ticketing software i want to post their `username and password` to another `form` in an `iframe`.

Basically the `iframe` contains a page in which i want them to be automatically logged in to. The login credentials for the ticketing software and the page are the same all i want to do is pass that credential to an `iframe` in which there is username and password field.

Like in jquery you can get .val of the what every is submitted and just send it to another form field.. i want to do that..

What is the best practice?

Comment: Can post to iFrames?

Comment: look into  CORS for Html5rocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `target` attribute on a form to point it to an `<iframe>` by name.

For example:

```
<form action="process_login_url" method="post" target="iframelogin" id="loginform">
  <input name="login" type="hidden" value="login" />
  <input name="password" type="hidden" value="p4ssw0rd" />
</form>
<iframe name="iframelogin">
<script>
// automatically post the form
document.getElementById('loginform').submit()
</script>
```

You need to pre-populate the hidden fields with user login and password, then the form is automatically sent to the iframe. `action` on your form has to be the other login processing url, not the login form itself (if these are separate). So basically the `action` attribute of the external form. Names of the input fields also have to match the target form's names.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/297suggf/2/ - note the `iframe` has no `src` attribute, it loads the url from `action` on the form with the POST data passed with the request. (It's some random website that allows testing POSTs).

I don't think it's a great idea, and it may not work if there's a protection on the receiving end (like a CSRF token), but youu may give it a shot if it's a last resort type situation